# javascript working in chrome but not working in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

this is used to Update the chips displayed in the field, this code is working on every browser other than the ie9, when i'm trying to get an output on the new field depending on input, i'm simply getting no value visible in the filed where as when I'm clicking othe filed then it redirects me to the modal page where i can able to see the value, also couldn't able to see any value in dom or error in console.

```
updateChips: function() {
    var me = this,
        clientWidth,
        totalChipWidth = 0,
        overflowCount = 0,
        overflowText = '';

    if (!this.rendered) {
        this.on('render', function() {
            me.updateChips();
        });
        return;
    }

    if (!this.inputEl) {
        return;
    }

    this.inputEl.update('');
    clientWidth = this.inputEl.dom.clientWidth - 50;
    Ext.Array.each(this.getInternalValue(), function(val) {
        var chip = me.inputEl.appendChild({
            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'b5chip',
            children: [
                {
                    tag: 'span',
                    cls: 'label',
                    children: val.title,
                    title: val.title
                }, {
                    tag: 'span',
                    cls: 'b5chipdelete',
                    children: B5.b5theme.Glyphs.asHtml(
                        B5.b5theme.Glyphs.CLOSE
                    )
                }
            ]
        });

        totalChipWidth += chip.dom.clientWidth;
        if (totalChipWidth > clientWidth) {
            chip.destroy();
            overflowCount += 1;
            overflowText = overflowText + val.title + '\n';
            return;
        }

        chip.down('.b5chipdelete').on('click', function(e) {
            var currentValue = me.getInternalValue(),
                recordId = val.id,
                values = Ext.Array.filter(currentValue, function(value) {
                    return value.id !== recordId;
                });
            me.setValue(values);

            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });

    if (overflowCount) { 
        var chip = me.inputEl.appendChild({
            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'b5overflowchip',
            children: [
                {
                    tag: 'span',
                    cls: 'label',
                    children: '+' + overflowCount,
                    title: overflowText
                }
            ]
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @Taplar there is no error showing in the console